# How does the Planck–Einstein relation imply discreteness?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, discrete

The relation is often stated as $E = h\nu$

Simple enough. But the frequency $\nu$ doesn't have to be a natural number or even an integer, correct? It can be any rational number or even any real number. So why is the energy $E$ quantized anyway? And if the given equation is technically faulty then how should it be written?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/73959/2451 . https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/169209/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency isn't even a property of photons, it's an artifact of the frame in which they are measured, so in a world with "only integer frequencies", a simple boost would ruin it. (Planck units aside).

The point of:

$$ E = h\nu $$

is that it is the minimum energy observed in electromagnetic wave with frequency $\nu$, and that the only possible energies are:

$$ E_n = nh\nu\,\,\,\,\{n=1,2,3,\dots\}$$

So the field is quantized, and $n$ is interpreted as the number of photons in the mode.

Comment: Thanks, that clear things up. But how would a mathematician interpret the equation? And have there been conflicts between physicists and mathematicians about what  particular equations actually mean? I'm not a purist myself, but I know most - if not all - mathematicians are.

Answer (score 0):

What the Planck-Einstein law implies is that if take any frequency $\nu$, irrespective of it being a natural number, rational number etc., then that light would come in photons, particles which can only have **specific amounts of energy** given by $E = nh\nu$. So basically, $n$ can only be a natural number. **The energy of the photon is discrete**. Not the frequency. And that is why the law holds. The frequency has no bounds or limitations, but the energy of any particular photons come in only discrete values.